# Angular Material MdSidebar - How to call .toggle() from typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am trying to sidenav toggle from another component, however when the .toggle() function gets called from my parent component it throws this error:

> AppComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: this.sidenav.toggle is not a function
>       at AppComponent.webpackJsonp.176.AppComponent.toggleNav (app.component.ts:25)

here is the code: app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { MdSidenav } from '@angular/material';
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent{
    title = 'CRS Management App';
    @ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav:MdSidenav;
    toggleNav(){
      this.sidenav.toggle();
    }
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<app-nav #navbar (nav)="toggleNav()"></app-nav>
<app-sidebar #sidenav></app-sidebar>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

the (nav) is emitted from the app-nav component.

sidebar.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.scss']
})
export class SidebarComponent {
    title = 'CRS';

  constructor() { }

}
```

sidebar.component.html:

```
 <md-sidenav-container class="container">
<!--SIDEBAR -->
    <md-sidenav #sidebar class="sidebar" mode="over" opened="true">

        <!-- MENU https://material.angular.io/components/component/list -->
         <div class="nav-links">
            <md-nav-list> <!--TODO Links -->
               <a md-list-item href="/one"> Option </a> <!--TODO Icon -->
               <a md-list-item href="/two"> Option </a> <!--TODO Icon-->
               <a md-list-item href="/three"> Option </a> <!--TODO Icon-->
               <span class="flex"></span><!--TODO Divider-->
               <a md-list-item href="/four"> _______ </a> <!--TODO Icon-->
               <a md-list-item href="/five"> Option </a> <!--TODO Icon -->
               <a md-list-item href="/six"> Option </a> <!--TODO Icon-->
               <a md-list-item href="/seven"> Option </a> <!--TODO Icon-->
               <a md-list-item href="/eight"> Option </a> <!--TODO Icon-->
            </md-nav-list>
        <!-- SETTINGS -->
            <!--TODO link to settings -->
            <!--TODO Convert to md-list-item -->
            <button md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Settings">
                Settings<md-icon>settings</md-icon> 
            </button>
        <!-- SETTINGS END -->
        </div>

    </md-sidenav>
<!-- SIDEBAR ENDS -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

I have tried using AfterViewInit, it throws:

> ERROR TypeError: this.sideNav.toggle is not a function at AppComponent.webpackJsonp.176.AppComponent.toggleNav (http://127.0.0.1:4200/main.bundle.js:171:22)

Comment: use `@ViewChild(MdSidenav) sidenav:MdSidenav` and call in the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook.

Comment: Can you post your template code?

Comment: @snorkpete 
'<app-nav #navbar (nav)="toggleNav()"></app-nav>
<app-sidebar #sidenav></app-sidebar>
<app-footer></app-footer>'

the (nav) event is coming from a separate component,

Comment: can you update your actual question? comments aren't the best place to put code samples.  And you have #sidenav reference variable for an <app-sidebar> component.  is this your own custom component?

Comment: Thankyou for your replies. I have tried the AfterViewInit previously, it just gives a different location for the same error `ERROR TypeError: this.sideNav.toggle is not a function
    at AppComponent.webpackJsonp.176.AppComponent.toggleNav (http://127.0.0.1:4200/main.bundle.js:171:22)`

Comment: apologies, i'm new here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The template ref **#sidenav** on the AppComponent refers to the SidebarComponent which does not have a toggle function.

You could add one to it which then calls the sidenav.toggle() and then you could call that from the AppComponent.

**sidebar.component.ts**

```
  import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
  import { MatSidenav} from '@angular/material';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-sidebar',
    templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
  })
  export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'CRS';
    @ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav: MatSidenav;
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    toggle() {
      this.sidenav.toggle();
    }
  }
```

**sidebar.component.html**

```
  <md-sidenav-container class="container">
    <md-sidenav #sidenav class="sidebar" mode="over" opened="true">
    ...

    </md-sidenav>      
 </md-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: little error, you mean `import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material';`  and not `import { MdSidenav } from '@angular/material';`

Comment: In more recent versions of Angular, use ```import { MatSidenav} from '@angular/material/sidenav';```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I didn't include MatSidenavModule in my component module imports list. That solved the problem. It looks like some other Material module has indirectly imports the SidenaveModule, that is the reason we didn't get the usual error when we don't import the module in our component.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`ngAfterViewInit` callback](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html), here's [a good example](http://learnangular2.com/viewChild/).